# Параметры коллекций java

Tags: java, коллекции

Встречаю различные варианты декларирования коллекций:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //1

List list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // 2

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(); //3
```

И совершенно нет ясности, какие объекты в какую коллекцию можно положить. Экспериментально выяснил, что в коллекцию 2 - можно добавить объекты (Object). А в коллекцию 3 - только с типом Integer.

**Вопрос 1:** как понять по декларированию, какие объекты может содержать коллекция?

**Вопрос 2:** для каких прикладных задач можно использовать первый, второй и третий вариант декларирования коллекций?

Comment: http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-Collections Вместо тысячи слов.

Comment: http://www.quizful.net/post/java-generics-tutorial - Дженерики. Ключ к пониманию коллекций.

Comment: По вопросу 1: Тот тип, что в угловых скобках - должен быть у объектов, которые может вмещать коллекция.
По вопросу 2: 1 и 3 - используем, когда нужно хранить изменяемый по вместимости массив целых чисел. 2 - когда нужно оперировать с коллекциями, которые могут содержать разные типы данных. Т.е. мы можем под list иметь как коллекцию целых, так и коллекцию строк или коллекцию коллекций. Про интерфейсы (в ООП или в Java в частности) рекомендую почитать в первую очередь. И про модель организации данных в памяти компьютера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр типа коллекции содержится в левой части, что написано в правой части значения [не имеет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357883/using-generics-on-right-hand-side-in-java-6).

Таким образом, записи (1, 3) полностью идентичны:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //1

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(); //3
```

Вы можете вписывать в правую часть параметр или не вписывать, как вам удобно. Компиляция (по ссылке выше) показала, что на время выполнения запись никак не влияет.
Тогда как в выражении 2:

```
List list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //2
```

Тип не указан в левой части, значит тип - любой объект `Object`.

Answer (score 10):

[quizful.net/post/Java-Collections](http://quizful.net/post/Java-Collections) - о Коллекциях в Java.
[quizful.net/post/java-generics-tutorial](http://quizful.net/post/java-generics-tutorial) - Дженерики. Ключ к пониманию коллекций.

**По вопросу 1:** Тот тип, что **в угловых скобках** `<>` - должен быть у объектов, которые может вмещать коллекция.

**По вопросу 2:** 1 и 3 - используем, когда нужно хранить изменяемый по вместимости массив целых чисел. 2 - когда нужно оперировать с коллекциями, которые могут содержать разные типы данных. Т.е. мы можем под `list` иметь как коллекцию целых, так и коллекцию строк или коллекцию коллекций. Про **интерфейсы** (в ООП или в Java в частности) рекомендую почитать в первую очередь. И про модель организации данных в памяти компьютера.

Если кратко, то все классы в Java - наследники класса `Object`. Интерфейс `List` определён как `public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>` (см. [docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)). Объявление `List list` можно читать как `List<Object> list`. Соответственно, раз в листе могут содержаться любые объекты, которые расширяют класс, который может содержать коллекция - то мы можем поместить под ссылку `list` объект листа объектов любого класса. ([arininav.ru/js/java04.htm](http://arininav.ru/js/java04.htm) см. пункты **5.4.1.3.** и **5.4.1.4.**)

Comment: Вы бы лучше написали почему во втором случае можно пхать что угодно, хотя справа написано `ArrayList<Integer>();`  Думаю автора это смущает

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно. Если кратко, то все классы в Java - наследники класса Object. Интерфейс List определён как public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> (см. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Объявление List list можно читать как List<Object> list. Соответственно, раз в листе могут содержаться любые объекты, которые расширяют класс, который может содержать коллекция - то мы можем поместить под ссылку list объект листа объектов любого класса. (http://www.arininav.ru/js/java04.htm см. пункты 5.4.1.3. и 5.4.1.4.)

Comment: В ответ)) всё в ответ))

Comment: Не осветили в вопросе, что означают угловые скобки в правой части  `new ArrayList<Integer>();` Наличие параметра в правой части на что-нибудь влияет?

Comment: Пришлось самому возвращаться в свой старый вопрос.